# JavaScript: Break from fetch then

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a possibility to break from a fetch-then-block. In particular: I want to test a condition and if it's true, the next 'then' should not be executed. Is that possible?

```
fetch(url).then(response => {
    return response.text();
}).then(text => {
    if (condition) {
        break
    }
}).then(...)
```

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: Why do you need 3 `then` blocks? Are you returning a `Promise` from the second one?

Comment: After you check your condition, again return a promise for the next then() to hande :)

Comment: if (condition) {
       return new Promise((res,rej)=>res('condition true'))
    }

Comment: @D.Pardal `then()` always returns a promise even if it resolves to undefined due to no explicit return

Comment: Explain your use case in more detail. People are left guessing what your higher level objective or problem is and therefore the best approach to solving it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could throw an error from the callback function of the `then()` method.

Throwing an error will reject the `Promise` returned by the `then()` method and will cause the callback function of the `catch()` method to execute instead of the next `then()` method(s).

```
fetch(url)
   .then(response => response.text())
   .then(text => {
       if (condition) {
          throw new Error('promise chain cancelled');
       }
    })
    .then(...)
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Ideally, you should throw an error with some custom name or error code that you can use in the `catch` block to detect whether the error was thrown because of the condition being true.

```
fetch(url)
   .then(response => response.text())
   .then(text => {
        if (condition) {
            const error = new Error('promise chain cancelled');
            error.name = 'CancelPromiseChainError';
            throw error;
        }
   })
   .then(...)
   .catch(error => {
       if (error?.name == 'CancelPromiseChainError') {
           // code to run when promise chain is cancelled
       }
   });
```

Comment: My error results in not calling `then` but going straight to `catch`, so no need for the `if`.